# Exception org.apache.jasper.JasperException:Unable to compile class for JSP: An error in jsp file:[/index.jsp] conn and DBConnect cannot be resolved

Tags: java, jsp

I'm using the latest TomCat version and I've recently installed Eclipse IDE for Java Developers - 2021-03

This is my class:[this is my class package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZSWI.png)

```
package com.DB;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class DBConnect {
    
    private static Connection conn;
    public static Connection getConn()
    {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ebook-app","root","password");
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        return conn;
    }

}
```

So this is my jsp code for class:

```
<%@page import="com.DB.DBConnect.* " %>
<% Connection conn=DBConnect.getConn();//My error in this line.why?
out.println(conn);
%>
```

I'm getting Error like this:

```
HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error
Type Exception Report

Message Unable to compile class for JSP:

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: [33] in the jsp file: [/index.jsp]
Connection cannot be resolved to a type
30: </div>
31: 
32: <%@page import="com.DB.DBConnect.* " %>
33: <% Connection conn=DBConnect.getConn();
34: out.println(conn);
35: %>
36: 


An error occurred at line: [33] in the jsp file: [/index.jsp]
DBConnect cannot be resolved
30: </div>
31: 
32: <%@page import="com.DB.DBConnect.* " %>
33: <% Connection conn=DBConnect.getConn();
34: out.println(conn);
35: %>
36: 


Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:103)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:213)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:482)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:392)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:362)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:346)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:605)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:400)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:378)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:326)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.

Apache Tomcat/9.0.43
```

[1st Error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3MEJs.png)
[2nd Error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzMKa.png)

Simply, What my problem is ,I'm getting the Error in jsp: line 33;
<% Connection conn=DBConnect.getConn(); //My error in this line.why?

I'm beginner for java,so please explain it in simple and clear way...

Answer (score 0):

Your package com.DB has only one class i.e. DBConnect. You can import till com.DB.* and instead of getting connection object in jsp and printing here in jsp, return the string representation or string value of connection object from one method in your java class and then print it here.